# Dual boot fails to boot ubuntu-Mate 17.04 on Windows 10 box

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I had Windows 10 installed on C:\ working well. I wanted to dual boot Linux so I installed via USB stick targeting a 2nd SSD installed for that purpose. When it came to where to place the boot code I selected the 2nd SSD "sdb." I didn't think to boot off that drive from the BIOS, expecting Grub to just work. I reinstalled using sda to place the boot but then ubuntu still would not boot. Ubuntu just displayed a screen but wouldn't even respond to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Delete</kbd>. I found Windows displayed on the Grub boot menu and it could boot but above it at the top of the list was ubuntu which did nothing beyond what I described above. I must have deleted the partitions and reinstalled ubuntu on sdb7 times each time trying to name a different partition on sdb. 
Perhaps I'll try again when I get up. I've been up all night trying.

**EDIT:** Okay...I have some really pertinent information.
I noticed an error message but, duhh, I ignored it thinking it insignificant.
It is displayed when I try to install ubuntu into my target machine. However, I tried my older computer where the errors did not appear and the install was successful. I photographed these messages and here is the text:

[     0.018063] ACPI Error: [\SB_.PCI0.XHC_.RHUB.HS11] Namespace lookup failure. AE_NOT_FOUND (20160930/dwsload-210)

[     0.018063] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, During name lookup/catalog (20160930/psobject_227)

[     0.018097] ACPI Exception: AE_NOT_FOUND, (SSDT:xh_rup08) while loading table (20160930/tbxfload-228)

[     0.024062] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 4 successful (20160930/tbxfload-246)

See this post about above:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1584407

Whatever this means it would appear to provide a reasonable explanation.

Comment: Perhaps the problem is with the graphics not being supported by the default drivers. You may need `nomodeset`. I think Ubuntu is correctly installed because Grub is working and Windows is booting.

Comment: Ignore these chars